# Why do I keep getting this "syntax error binary base error" in EDA playground?

Tags: verilog

I tried several things, but I keep getting this error in EDA playground. How do I fix it? I'm trying to implement a system to add, subtract, etc., and get flags for ADDS and SUBS. I tried creating a `reg` variable and then assigning the flags to that, but that didn't work. The code runs when I don't use any flags in my case statements. Here is my code and the error below:

```
module alu(A,B, ALU_Sel,ALU_Out,Carry,Zero,Overflow,Negative,ALU_Result);
  
  input wire[63:0] A,B;  // ALU 64-bit Inputs                 
  input wire [3:0] ALU_Sel;// ALU Selection
  reg C;
  reg Z;
  reg O;
  reg N;
  output reg [63:0] ALU_Out; // ALU 8-bit Output
  output reg Carry; // Carry Out Flag
  output reg Zero;
  output reg Overflow;
  output reg Negative;
  output reg [63:0] ALU_Result;
  
    assign ALU_Out = ALU_Result; // ALU out
  assign Carry=C;
  assign Zero = Z;
  assign Overflow = O;
  asssign Negative = N;
     always @(*)
    begin
      Carry=0;
      Zero=0;
      Overflow=0;
      Negative=0;
      
      case(ALU_Sel[3:0])
          4'b0000:  //AND -h0
          ALU_Result = A & B;
          C=1;
          
          4'b0010: //ADD -h2
          ALU_Result = A + B;
          
          4'b0011: //ADDS -h3
          ALU_Result = A + B;
          //CREATE FLAGS HERE
          //reg Carry = 1;
          
          4'b1100: //EOR -h12
          ALU_Result =A^B;
          
          4'b0110: //SUB -h6
          ALU_Result = A-B;
          
          4'b0111: //SUBS -h7
          ALU_Result = A-B;
          //CREATE FLAGS HERE
          
          4'b1001: //LSL -h9
          ALU_Result = A << B;
          
          4'b0001: //OR -h1
          ALU_Result = A | B;
          
         endcase
      end
endmodule
```

---

```
ERROR VCP2000 "Syntax error. Unexpected token: =." "design.sv" 20  21
ERROR VCP2000 "Syntax error. Unexpected token: =." "design.sv" 31  13
ERROR VCP2000 "Syntax error. Unexpected token: 4'b0011[_BINARY_BASE]." "design.sv" 36  18
ERROR VCP2000 "Syntax error. Unexpected token: 4'b1100[_BINARY_BASE]." "design.sv" 41  18
ERROR VCP2000 "Syntax error. Unexpected token: 4'b0110[_BINARY_BASE]." "design.sv" 44  18
ERROR VCP2000 "Syntax error. Unexpected token: 4'b0111[_BINARY_BASE]." "design.sv" 47  18
ERROR VCP2000 "Syntax error. Unexpected token: 4'b1001[_BINARY_BASE]." "design.sv" 51  18
ERROR VCP2000 "Syntax error. Unexpected token: 4'b0001[_BINARY_BASE]." "design.sv" 54  18
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing bracketing `begin`/`end` keywords around each case branch item.

```
module alu(
  input wire[63:0] A,B,  // ALU 64-bit Inputs                 
  input wire [3:0] ALU_Sel,// ALU Selection
  output reg [63:0] ALU_Out, // ALU 8-bit Output
  output reg Carry, // Carry Out Flag
  output reg Zero,
  output reg Overflow,
  output reg Negative,
  output reg [63:0] ALU_Result
);
  
always @(*)
    begin
      Carry=0;
      Zero=0;
      Overflow=0;
      Negative=0; 
      case(ALU_Sel[3:0])
          4'b0000:  begin //AND -h0
          ALU_Result = A & B;
          Carry=1;
          end
          4'b0010: begin //ADD -h2
          ALU_Result = A + B;
          end
          4'b0011: begin //ADDS -h3
          ALU_Result = A + B;
          //CREATE FLAGS HERE
          //reg Carry = 1;
          end
          4'b1100: begin//EOR -h12
          ALU_Result =A^B;
          end
          4'b0110: begin //SUB -h6
          ALU_Result = A-B;
          end
          4'b0111: begin//SUBS -h7
          ALU_Result = A-B;
          //CREATE FLAGS HERE
          end
          4'b1001: begin //LSL -h9
          ALU_Result = A << B;
          end
          4'b0001: begin//OR -h1
          ALU_Result = A | B;
          end
         endcase
      end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your code.

The 1st error you see on EDAplayground is on line 20 (using the Adlec simulator), which is this line:

```
  asssign Negative = N;
```

In my web browser, EDAplayground applies syntax highlighting to the code, where Verilog keywords are colored and other works are in black print.  This shows the `asssign` word as black, which means it does not recognize it as a Verilog keyword.  It is a typo; change it to:

```
  assign Negative = N;
```

The next error is this line:

```
      Carry=1;
```

On its own, the syntax is fine, but taken together with the line above it, there is an error.  When multiple statements are used inside a `case` statement, they must be enclosed by the `begin/end` keywords.

```
      4'b0000:  //AND -h0
      begin
          ALU_Result = A & B;
          C=1;
      end
```

After making the above changes, there are still errors.  You make multiple assignments to the same signal (`Carry`): one using the `assign` statement, and another inside the `always` block.  You can't do both, which means you need to decide which is the one you want.  Deleting the `assign` statements would remove all the errors from your code.

Judging by your comments ("`//CREATE FLAGS HERE`"), I assume you are not yet finished with the design.  For example, the `Z` signal is not assigned a value.